# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c++, c

I am getting the above error during compilation:

Structure:

```
struct connection_handlers
{
  int m_fd;

}

struct connection_handlers ** _queue;

int main()
{

_queue = (struct connection_handlers **) malloc ( 3* sizeof ( struct connection_handlers *)); //Allocating space for 3 struct pointers

for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
     _queue[i]->m_fd=-1;
}//Initializing to -1

//.....
//I assign this varaible to the file descriptor returned by accept and then
//at some point of time i try to check the same variable and it gives compilatio error.

for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
if (_queue[i]->m_fd!=-1)
}//It give error at this line. 

}
```

What could be the reason for error.

Thanks

Comment: What error u r getting ? could u provide more code ?

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this question both C and C++, here is what is wrong with your C++.

- don't put `struct` inside your casts
- don't use implicit `int` for your loop counters
- struct declarations need a terminating `;`
- `_queue` is declared with a messed-up type
- your last loop is missing

Once you clean that up it compiles fine.

```
#include <cstdlib>

struct connection_handlers {
  int m_fd;
};

int main() {
  connection_handlers**  _queue = (connection_handlers**) malloc(3*sizeof (connection_handlers*));

  for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    _queue[i]->m_fd=-1;
  }

  for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    if (_queue[i]->m_fd!=-1)
      ; // DOES NOTHING
  }
}
```

Comment: In C, you have to put `struct`, `connection_handlers` is not a type in C.  But in C, the `malloc()` call is better written as `_queue = malloc(3 * sizeof *_queue);` anyway, avoiding the need for a type.

Answer (score 1):

`_queue[i]` is a `connection_handlers *`. You can't compare that to `-1`, which is an `int`. Did you mean to check `_queue[i]->m_fd`?

Comment: Yes. I meant _queue[i]->m_fd. Edited the question. Thanks Karl.